# c# Add some values at List

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq

I write some code which do:

```
List<DataRow> rows=new <DataRow>();
foreach (DataRow dtRow in sqlRows)
{
    foreach (DataRow dtRowId in dttRows1)
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(dtRowId[0]) == Convert.ToInt32(dtRow[1]))
            rows.Add(dtParRow);
    }
}
```

Can I write it some more effective way? May be use LINQ? Or some other algorihtm?

P.S. sqlRows and dttRows1 is List. I grub it from table with query like this:"Select * from table name";

Comment: Where does "dtParRow" comes from?

Comment: What is `sqlRows` and dttRows1 `exactly`?

Comment: A simple LINQ query should indeed do the job.

Comment: I guess he is trying to do inner join.

Comment: What do you mean by "more effective"? Are you looking for efficiency? What type are the values of `dtRowId[0]` and `dtRow[1]` at the moment?

Comment: Who cares from where the rows come from as long as we are dealing with IEnumerable's?

Comment: A LINQ query will be more concise in terms of coding but will result in two nested loops and pretty much the same run time. What are you looking for, less coding or a shorter runtime?

Comment: Please for the sake of the person reading your code (you and maybe a collegue) always aim for readable code! You can always make a fancy one-liner which no one can read.

Comment: @Tarik: This can be expressed as an inner join which can be more efficient than the nested loop.

Comment: @JonSkeet If you mean more efficient in terms of run time, please explain why. LINQ is but syntactic sugar to underlying code using IEnumerator within loops.

Comment: @Tarik: Yes, I'm aware of what LINQ does - but if you use the `Join` method, that builds a map from one collection based on the key selector (iterating over it once), and then uses that map while iterating over the second collection (iterating over that once too). It needs to iterate over all matching values while performing the second iteration, but if you assume an average of one match per row, this gives a running time of O(M + N) instead of O(M * N). All that *could* be done without LINQ, of course - but LINQ allows you to write it very concisely.

Comment: i think that should use inner join

Answer (score 1):

You could just use LINQ with a join, which would be more efficient than the nested approach:

```
var query = from dtRow in sqlRows
            join dtRowId in dttRows1
              on Convert.ToInt32(dtRow[1]) equals Convert.ToInt32(dtRowId[0])
            select ???; // dtParRow is unknown. Did you mean dtRow?
var list = query.ToList();
```

Note that if those values are already `int` values (so don't need parsing etc) then just cast instead:

```
var query = from dtRow in sqlRows
            join dtRowId in dttRows1
              on (int) dtRow[1] equals (int) dtRowId[0]
            select ???; // dtParRow is unknown. Did you mean dtRow?
var list = query.ToList();
```

Or use the [`Field<T>` extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301394%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (again, only if they're already `int` values which don't need converting):

```
var query = from dtRow in sqlRows
            join dtRowId in dttRows1
              on dtRow.Field<int>(1) equals dtRowId.Field<int>(0)
            select ???; // dtParRow is unknown. Did you mean dtRow?
var list = query.ToList();
```

Comment: Would it be dtRow.Field<int>(index), better than casting or converting?

Comment: @Typist: Yes for the former - but I don't think it will do (say) string conversions. Checking and editing now...

Comment: string conversions? did I miss anything

Comment: @Typist: We don't know the types of the values. If they're actually strings, then `Convert.ToInt32` will parse them - in that case, neither the cast nor the call to `Field` will work.

Comment: if required,  condition for null( DbNull.Value) check, otherwise exception might come on casting.  where null check code should be added? in "where" clause or in join condition?

Comment: @AmitGaikwad: I'd probably add a `where` clause in this case, to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite that like

```
List<DataRow> rows= (from dtRow in sqlRows 
                     from dtRowId in dttRows1 
                     where Convert.ToInt32(dtRowId[0]) == Convert.ToInt32(dtRow[1])         
                     select dtParRow).ToList();
```

this is not always the better way. Yor code is a lot more clear.

Comment: Well it doesn't help that you've decided to put the whole thing on one line - it's a lot clearer using multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to find some items depending on a condition and add it to a separate list.

Try "join" in LINQ. Kindly have a look at the below example.

```
 public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

 var customerList1 = new List<Customer>(new[]
        {
            new Customer {Id = 1, Name = "AAA"},
            new Customer {Id = 1, Name = "BBB"},
            new Customer {Id = 1, Name = "CCC"}
        });

        var customerList2 = new List<Customer>(new[]
        {
            new Customer {Id = 1, Name = "AAA"},
            new Customer {Id = 1, Name = "BBB"},
            new Customer {Id = 1, Name = "CCC"},
            new Customer {Id = 1, Name = "DDD"}
        });

        var commonCustomers = customerList1.Join(customerList2, x => x.Name, y=>y.Name,(a,b)=>a).ToList();
```

So according to your question, what I think you should write is, (kindly note that the below code has not been tested)

var rows = sqlRows.Join(dttRows1, x => Convert.ToInt32(x[0]), y=>Convert.ToInt32(y[0]),(a,b)=>a).ToList();

Thanks,
Cheranga